# glmnet: How do I know which factor level of my response is coded as 1 in logistic regression

Tags: r, regression, logistic-regression, glmnet

I have a logistic regression model that I made using the `glmnet` package. My response variable was coded as a factor, the levels of which I will refer to as "a" and "b".

The mathematics of logistic regression label one of the two classes as "0" and the other as "1". The feature coefficients of a logistic regression model are either positive, negative, or zero. If a feature "f"'s coefficient is positive, then increasing the value of "f" for a test observation x increases the probability that the model classifies x as being of class "1".

My question is: Given a `glmnet` model, how do you know how `glmnet` mapped your data's factor labels {"a", "b"} to the underlying mathematics' factor labels {"0", "1"}? Because you need to know that to interpret the model's coefficients properly.

You can figure this out manually by experimenting with the output of the `predict` function when applied to toy observations. But it would be nice to how `glmnet` implicitly handles that mapping to speed up the interpretation process.

Thank you!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Have a look at `?glmnet` (page 9 of https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/glmnet/glmnet.pdf):

```
y

response variable. ... For family="binomial" should be either a factor
with two levels, or a two-column matrix of counts or proportions (the 
second column is treated as the target class; for a factor, the last
level in alphabetical order is the target class) ...
```

Isn't it clear now? If you have `"a"` and `"b"` as your factor levels, `"a"` is coded as 0, while `"b"` is coded 1.

Such treatment is really standard. It is related to how R codes factor automatically, or how you code these factor levels yourself. Look at:

```
## automatic coding by R based on alphabetical order
set.seed(0); y1 <- factor(sample(letters[1:2], 10, replace = TRUE))
## manual coding
set.seed(0); y2 <- factor(sample(letters[1:2], 10, replace = TRUE),
                   levels = c("b", "a"))

# > y1
# [1] b a a b b a b b b b
# Levels: a b
# > y2
# [1] b a a b b a b b b b
# Levels: b a

# > levels(y1)
# [1] "a" "b"
# > levels(y2)
# [1] "b" "a"
```

Whether you use `glmnet()`, or simply `glm()`, the same thing happens.

Comment: I definitely don't find the help in glmnet particularly clear. Thanks for your answer though.

Comment: So if you manually encode your factor, is the first level the positive class?

Comment: @JeffBezos **Always** the 2nd level.